# advanced array of bytes searching

Tags: arrays, search

I have a binary file and i have to track a "dynamic array of bytes" in this file , this array is something like:

d0 30 60 XX 5d 48

Where XX can be any HEX value

I need to find all the occurences of this array in the binary file , i mean all the array of bytes that starts with D0 30 60 (hex) , followed by "XX" (random hex byte) , followed by 5D 48 (hex).

is there any tool or a python script that can do that ?

Comment: You can take input from file via `open`  then `explode` with space

Comment: can you explain what do you mean with "explode" ?

Comment: Sorry my mistake . By explode I mean `split`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this :

```
import re
fil = open("myfile.txt")
txt = fil.read()
mo = re.match(r'd0 3d0 30 60 ([0-9a-f][0-9a-f]) 5d 48',txt,re.M)
```

I have not much used [regex in python](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm) earlier. I used regex in Php etc so have alook at that link.

Edit : Might be better,

```
f = open('test.txt', 'r')
s = re.findall(r'd0 3d0 30 60 ([0-9a-f][0-9a-f]) 5d 48',f.read())
```

Comment: i said i want to find all the arrays of bytes which starts with the hex values D0 30 60 followed by a random HEX value "XX" then followed with the HEX values D5 48

Comment: i said i want to find all the arrays of bytes which starts with the hex values D0 30 60 followed by a random HEX value "XX" then followed with the HEX values D5 48

Comment: You can also use `findall()` chk https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions

Comment: yes it did , thank you so much , findall was just what i want :)